How does a linear map over $L^{1}$ spaces interact with integration
Lets say we have a linear map $T:L^{1}(\lambda)\rightarrow L^{1}(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is some arbitrary measure. Lets say we have some function $F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t,x)d\lambda(t)$ where we assume that $f\in L^{1}(\lambda,\mathbb{R}^{2})$. By Fubini we know that $F(x),f_{t}(x):=f(t,x)$ are both $L^{1}(\lambda)$. As such it makes sense to take $T(F(x))$. My question is, is it true that $T(F(x))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}T(f(t,x))d\lambda(t)$? The motivation for this question comes from signal processing: if we make the following observation that $x(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)d\tau$ where $\delta$ is the dirac function (distribution?), then for any linear time-invariant system we can say that $H(x(t))=x(t)\ast h(t)$ where $h(t)$ is the impulse response. One of the steps in the derivation I was given in class was
$$ H(x(t))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x(\tau)H(\delta(t-\tau))d\tau$$ The professor claims this follows from linearity of $H$ but I am not exactly sure how. Any help would be appreciated!
Edit: It seems that in general $T$ needs to be a bounded linear map, as geetha290krm and Bruno B stated below, for $T(F(x))=\int_{\mathbb{R}}T(f(t,x))d\lambda(t)$ to hold. However, it seems like the only requirements on $H$ be that it is linear and time invariant. There is no condition that states it needs to be bounded/continuous. I suspect the commutativity of $H$ with the integral has to do with some nuance of how the dirac distribution/function is defined but I am not sure how.

Certainly false if $T$ is just linear. You need continuity of $T$. Also, the word  functional is used when the codomain is the scalar field (which is not the case here).

Thank you for the correction I have fixed my post!

Whether you use Bochner or Gel'fand/Pettis integrals, then you can identify $f$ to $\tilde{f} : t \mapsto (x \mapsto f(t, \cdot))$, and thus see it as a function from $L^1(\mathbb{R}, L^1(\lambda), \lambda)$, i.e. an integrable function which is "integrable-function-valued".
It is then a simple consequence of a result which states that bounded operators commute with the integral, which means in your case that, if $T$ is assumed continuous:
$$T(F) = T \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \tilde{f}(t)\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)\right) = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} T(\tilde{f}(t))\mathrm{d}\lambda(t)\right)$$
Though of course that didn't say much if that's exactly the result you're missing.
Either by definition (Gel'fand-Pettis integrals) or by some probably simple theory (Bochner), the integral commutes already with continuous functionals, and is actually characterised by that commutativity with functionals (uniqueness of the integral then comes from a corollary of Hahn-Banach for example).
Composition of a bounded functional $\Lambda \in Y^*$ by a bounded operator $T : X \to Y$ then yields a bounded functional $\Lambda \circ T \in X^*$, so that commutativity of the integral with bounded operators is quick to prove by just "attaching and detaching $\Lambda$ to and from $T$" and using the aforementioned characterisation (left as an exercise).
(Bonus: with some work, one can show that the integral actually commutes with closed operators, but that's likely out of the scope of this question).

Thank you very much for your informative answer! I was not aware this characterization, I guess I have something to read about haha. As you and geetha290krm both state, it seems that $T$ needs to be a bounded operator. But I believe the Linear Time-invariant operator does not necessarily have to be bounded? Or at least the derivation I got had no mention of such a condition. Is it possible that there are some subtleties with the Dirac distribution that allows for the commutativity with general linear operators?

@ManseejKhatri I have no clue. But also you should note that your $H$ is not in the same situation as your $T$, you are trying to apply $H$ on a distribution which is not a function, let alone a $L^1$ one. A way to circumvent this rigorously would be to try to work with a negative Sobolev space I suppose, but I don't know effective that would be.
